# Taxonomy terms with associated nodes: display page by page navigation in node page?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels

Hi i have a content type called **Product** and have fields(title,description,code,image) and also have vocabulary **categories** like below formate

```
parent term 1 
 -child term 1
    --sub child term 1.1
    --sub child term 1.2
    --sub child term 1.3
    --sub child term 1.4
    --sub child term 1.5
parent term 2
  --child term 2
    --sub child term 2.1
    --sub child term 2.2
    --sub child term 2.3
    --sub child term 2.4
    --sub child term 2.5
.
.
parent term 5
  --child term 5
    --sub child term 5.1
    --sub child term 5.2
    --sub child term 5.3
    --sub child term 5.4
    --sub child term 5.5
```

so i want to display my product node page first **parent terms list** when i click parent term 1 then it's display all related child terms in next page after that when click child term 1 display all related sub child terms list in another page after that when i click sub child term 1.1 need to display related products list with above fields.Please find below flow of screen shots.

**Taxonomy Parent Terms list**
Step 1
[image]

Step 2 when i clk Parent term 1 need to display all related child terms in another page like below 
[image]

step 3 when i clk child term 1 need to display all related sub child terms in another page like below 
[image]

step 4 when i clk sub child term 1.1 need to display all related node i.e product items list with above fields info.
[image]
Please advice
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to use [view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Step 1: Create a new view from Administration > Structure > View. Click on + Add new view.

Step 2: Give a name to your new view. From '**Show**' select Taxonomy terms and from type select appropriate taxonomy vocabulary (I assume name is 'product' here). Check either page or block and click '**Continue & edit**'.

Step 3: In First Page or Block under '**Filter Criteria**' click on Add and select **Taxonomy Vocabulary** and set it to use **product**. Click on Add again from **Filter Criteria** and select **Taxonomy term** and set it to *Parent term 1, Parent term 2, ....*. Now in preview section you will see the Parent terms.

Step 4: Under **FIELDS** click on Add and select **Taxonomy term: Term ID** and click on **Apply**. In **Configure field** page check on **Exclude from display** and click on apply. (I assume Taxonomy term: Name is already there.)

Step 5: Rearrange the order of fields by clicking on drop down icon besides **Add** under **FIELDS**. Make user the **Term ID** appears above **Term Name** and **Apply**.

Step 6: Click on **Taxonomy term: Term Name** and expand **REWRITE RESULTS**. Click the checkbox *Rewrite the output of this field* and in text area name **Text**, type in [name] and **Apply**.

Step 7: Create a new page in same view **+Add** > **Page** or create a different view as in Step 1 & 2.

Step 8: In new view page set the path under **PAGE SETTINGS** to *subchild/tid* (here tid refers to parent tid or taxonomy id).

Step 9: Follow the steps 3 to 6. Instead of Parent term 1, select Child term 1.1, Child term 1.2, ... assuming Parent is 1. And set href to *child/tid* for step 6 here tid refers to child term 1.* tid.

Step 10: Follow the same procedure as in step 8 & 9 for other child terms.

Step 11: Follow the same procedure as in Step 8 to 10. However set *path* under **Page Settings** to *subchild/tid* and href attribute for step 6 would be *product/tid*, here tid is subchild tid or taxonomy ID.

Step 12: Follow the same procedure as in Step 11 for all subchild terms.

For Displaying Products:

Step 1: Create a new View from Administration > Structure > View. Click on **+ Add new view**.

Step 2: Select **Content** from Show with appropriate type. Check on page and click on **Continue & edit**.

Step 3: Set the *path* in **Page Settings** to *product/tid* and from **Filter Criteria** select the **Taxonomy term** appropriate to the product to be displayed.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay@sarathkm.i have followed your steps and created block as well as page but little bit confusing setting path and rewrite results both block as well as page can you please add some more steps for exact my requirement clearly if possiable screen shot

Comment: Hi @sarathkm i have followed your steps nothing displayed when click on parent terms the flow what i expect not getting from above procedure

Comment: Thanks for screen shots..i have done same thing but when i click parent terms need to go url associated child terms display page but above screen shot taking page not found page(parent/[tid] ?).I have created 3 pages in first page displayed all parent terms then second page displayed all child terms and   third pages displayed all products i need dynamic url flow from 1st page to final product display. can you please share complete all screens with compare to above my sample flow pics